# How does Bazel track files so quickly?

Tags: bazel

I can't find any information about how Bazel tracks file. The documentation doesn't mention if they use something like facebook's watchman.

It obviously takes some kind of hash and compares, but how exactly does it do it? Because it knows if things hasn't changed immediately and it wouldn't be able to read all those files in such a short time.

Also if you are watching many files it would take up a lot of space with a mono repo like Google? I know that is one of the problems scaling git because "git status" will become to slow unless some intelligent caching is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bazel uses OS filesystem monitoring APIs like inotify on Linux and FSEvents on Mac OS

Check out these classes:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/c5d0b208f39353ae3696016c2df807e2b50848f4/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/skyframe/DiffAwareness.java

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/1d2932ae332ca0c517570f559c6dc0bac430b263/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/skyframe/LocalDiffAwareness.java

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/c5d0b208f39353ae3696016c2df807e2b50848f4/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/skyframe/MacOSXFsEventsDiffAwareness.java

Comment: I like the code references, straight to the source +1, thanks @ahumsky! Some of it is a bit difficult to understand still but it is a great entrypoint, also knowing that it uses the standard events like watchman.